# How do I extract an image from a video to use it as a thumbnail

Tags: php, javascript, video-streaming

i am using JW player to streaming my video. i just wants to know how to split the images from the video , my users uploading the video for my player.In the left hand side I wants to display  the images of the video if i click the image the correspond video path is passed through on click event so for this i need the image from the video so it is possible to split the images from the video using the php or js or else is it any other way to do this please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ffmpeg to extract an image from a video.

i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i input.dv -r 25 -f image2 images%05d.png
```

So if I were you I would extract a frame from the video when you upload it and store it in some directories as long as the video

If you are wondering how you can invoke ffmpeg from php see the [`system`](http://fr.php.net/system) or [`exec`](http://fr.php.net/exec) functions

Comment: there are several program execution functions in PHP, choose what you think is better for you. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Comment: yes its working , in my system ffmpeg is not installed properly that only i am faceing this issue now i re-install the ffmpeg and execute the above code now its working fine.